# reference passing from python to boost::python and back to python

Tags: c++, python, boost

I am new to python and boost::python and please pardon my ignorance .

My code has a python - C++ interaction which is done via boost::python .
I am passing an python dictionary reference to C++ :

C++ code :

```
boost::python::class_<ABC> ("ABC")

    .def("set_input",&ABC::set_input)
    ;

struct ABC {

boost::python::dict* signal_dictionary ;

 void insert_into_dict(int key,CellData cell_data) {

    if (!signal_dictionary->has_key(key) { 
       signal_dictionary->operator[](key)  = cell_data;
   }
 }

void set_input(boost::python::dict &signal_dict_t ) {
     signal_dictionary = &signal_dict_t;
}
```

My idea is to pass the address of the python dict to C++ . Populate data in C++ . And access it in python when the enitre population is done .
The function insert_into_dict is called intermittently and it populates data in the dict.
But i am getting the following Error :
**AttributeError: 'Boost.Python.function' object has no attribute '_*contains*_'**

This is coming from : signal_dictionary->has_key(key) .
It seems like boost::python reads signal_dictionary as boost::python::function even though its a boost::python::dict .
Is there any way of typecasting it to boost::python::dict .

Thanks in advance !!!